# iPhone XR returns correct nativeBounds but has wrong screen size on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios12

My project target iOS - 11 and later. It has correct Launch images assets for XR and XS Max with appropriate dimensions. On simulator my app works as expected on both XR and XS Max.

But, users reported UI issues on real devices. After some research it looks like on real device this

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size
```

returns correct values. But seems like device itself think that it has iPhone X screen size (like when i do not use correct launch screen images). And in my opinion it returns wrong values with

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size
```

this one i believe returns values like it's not iPhone XR but iPhone X.

Did someone face such an issue too?

Comment: You better add some code. Then we might understand what you mean by *wrong bounds* and *real wrong bounds* and *nativeBounds*.

Comment: Fixed question a bit. I believe it should be easier to understand now.

Comment: You talk about *correct* and *wrong* values. You better specify what values you expect and what values you get. Otherwise the question is still too vague.

Comment: And by the way: to what value have you set the Base SDK in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the trouble was in the specific user device settings.
Settings -> Display & brightness -> Display zoom switch to ON.
This cause to return wrong

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size
```

values runtime

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same question, and I found the reason. You could check the **LaunchImage** in the **assets**. Is there an image for the iPhone XR. If you don't have the **iPhone XR LaunchImage**, the screen size of XR will compute with the the iPhone X. So **make a LaunchImage for XR**.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Please read question carefully. It has correct launch images.

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone XR does not use the same size in (virtual) points than the iPhone X or iPhone XS does. It uses the same point dimensions like the new iPhone XS Max, but is rendered only with `@2x` instead of `@3x`, like the Max does (lower pixel per inch density). You can read more about screen sizes, points, rendered dimensions etc. for each iPhone model [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions).

The missing templates for launch images in XCAssets also affect the new generation of iPads, as e.g. the new iPad Pro 11" slightly differs from the standard 3/4 aspect ratio, the other iPads have. Diving deeper into the missing templates issue brought me to this [radar post](https://openradar.appspot.com/22915712) from 2015 about missing iPad Pro App Icon and Launch Image templates, where the comment states:

`[...] and Developer relations reported in a radar comment that they no longer support launch images and will not be adding the iPad pro launch image size to asset catalogs.`

It seems like Apple is discouraging the use of launch images inside XCAssets and proposes to use `Launch Screen.storyboard` instead. It will "auto-size" to the correct dimensions (and respectively the outputs of `UIScreen.main.bounds` and `UIScreen.main.nativeBounds`) depending on the used device or simulator.

Comment: Interesting info, thanks. But in my case the trouble was in a specific user device settings. See my answer below.